# What are all the costumes available in the US version?

Tags: tales-of-graces-f

There are many costumes available in the game (some in-game and others DLC in the Japanese version). It seems they are also releasing some new costumes on PSN.

What are all the available costumes (including any DLC) for the US version and how can they be obtained?

Comment: Had to check Wikipedia for this, I thought the tag was a typo.

Comment: In addition, could you remove the section of your question asking about upcoming costumes? We do not allow speculation of the future of games on the site. If more costumes are released in the future, they can be added to an existing answer.

Comment: So far, I've found two costumes on my own: One for Sophie, at Turtlez HQ.  The other for Asbel, from a title, Honorary Knight.  I'm currently more or less at the end boss.  Not in the future arc, just normal end boss.

Comment: The game is out in Japan with all the costumes, asking when those costumes come to the US is speculation? Rather, asking if there have been announcements.